# Can we use if condition to compare two dates in BATCH SCRIPT?

Tags: batch-file

As an example, Can I Compare dates by:

```
    for /d %%a in ("D:\Harshitha\Batch_Script\*") do (
        if "%%~ta" LSS "%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy%" (
            echo hi
        ) else (
            echo bye
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't use If directly to compare two dates.

We have to convert two dates to Julian date. Then we have to calculate the difference between them and then we can tell which is greater and which is lower.

> Julian date: the interval of time in days and fractions of a day, since January 1, 4713 BC Greenwich noon.

With Julian date, the comparison is a piece of cake!

```
@Echo Off
:: Replace yyyy mm dd with original date
Call :JDate yyyy mm dd 
Set Date1=%JDate%
:: Here another date goes in yyyy mm dd format
Call :JDate yyyy mm dd
Set Date2=%JDate%
:: Comparison
If %Date1% Lss %Date2% (
  Echo Hi
) Else (
  Echo Hello
)
:JDate
SET MM=%2
SET DD=%3
IF %MM:~0,1% EQU 0 SET MM=%MM:~1%
IF %DD:~0,1% EQU 0 SET DD=%DD:~1%
SET /A Month1=( %MM% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1=%1 + 4800
SET /A JDate=1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MM% - 2 -12 * %Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DD% - 32075
SET Month1=
SET Year1=
GOTO :EOF
```

The Julian date conversion code is from https://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php

Comment: If the correct sequence of Conditional testing is applied to the data, It's not strictly true that dates have to be converted to Julian. Many ways to Solve the Problem though.